# Syntax error in retrieving data from SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

When running the following code I get a sqlite3.OperationalError: near XX error...

The code is in python and is the following:

```
def get(item_id='', table='groups', field='id', encrypt=True):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    if item_id == '':
        sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table)
        c.execute(sqlstr)
    else:
        if encrypt:
            item_id = encryption.encrypt(item_id)
        sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}={}".format(table, field, item_id)
        c.execute(sqlstr)
```

considering as variables the following:

- table = 'groups'
- field = 'id'
- encrypt = True
  and considering that the value returned by **encryption.encrypt(item_id)** is 'gAAAAABe7UPHni1WJ1pSaljNj30k_SX-xGEfyCNMwO-3Pgjm1I57ROxSq5liNnm8yk5pjv0ZY7SyTUMIYqZrOyLeLQZNZ63iMw==' , I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\.env\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\promise.py", line 57, in run
    self._result = self.pooled_function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\fff_automation\bots\telebot\editgroup.py", line 10, in edit_group
    group = database.get(chat_id)[0]
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\fff_automation\modules\database.py", line 149, in get
    c.execute(sqlstr)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'gAAAAABe7UPHni1WJ1pSaljNj30k_SX-xGEfyCNMwO-3Pgjm1I57ROxSq5liNnm8yk5pjv0ZY7SyTUMIYqZrOyLeLQZNZ63iMw=='": syntax error
```

I tried adding '' around the {} of the item_id field in the sqlstr,

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}='{}'".format(table, field, item_id)
```

but by doing that, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\.env\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\promise.py", line 57, in run
    self._result = self.pooled_function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\fff_automation\bots\telebot\editgroup.py", line 10, in edit_group
    group = database.get(chat_id)[0]
  File "d:\dhfwi\Projects\FridaysForFuture\fff-transparency-wg\fff_automation\modules\database.py", line 149, in get
    c.execute(sqlstr)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "gAAAAABe7Ue7Yg6OP2ipWHGAXfZCiCVgbpdPso3noPYCjW4ds9rY8Yg9HN0Dhm10DDh7wYQ3kf2OuSabHlxcrg5xzwEdO4V31Q": syntax error
```

Comment: Does that item contain single quotes within its value?

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing `item_id` as a parameter with qmark placeholder since quote confusion may be the issue:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=?".format(table, field)
# sqlstr = f"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {field}=?"    # F-String (Python 3.6+)

c.execute(sqlstr, (item,))
```